# Determine highest precision type for corresponding floating point and complex types

Tags: c++, c++20

To deduce the highest precision type for floating point and complex types, i.e.

- `float`/`double`/`long double` results in  `long double`,
- `std::complex<T>` results in `std::complex<long double>`,

my attempt ( [live example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZUFyuUdWPkVd8jCO) ) feels very clumsy:

```cpp
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_complex : std::false_type {};

template <std::floating_point T>
struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_complex_v = is_complex<T>::value;

template <typename T>
struct highest_precision_type
{
    // none for arbitrary type
};

template <typename T>
    requires std::is_floating_point_v<T>
struct highest_precision_type<T>
{
    typedef long double type;
};

template <typename T>
    requires is_complex_v<T>
struct highest_precision_type<T>
{
    typedef std::complex<long double> type;
};

int main()
{
    auto f  = highest_precision_type<float>::type{1};
    auto cf = highest_precision_type<std::complex<float>>::type{0, 1};
    
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f), long double> );
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(cf), std::complex<long double>> );
}
```

Is there a more concise way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: IIRC, `long double` and `std::complex<long double>` are guaranteed to always be the highest precision.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Agreed. `highest_precision_type<T>` is intended to be used in templated code to elevate intermediate values to these highest precision types to reduce rounding and cancellation errors.

Comment: @RenéRichter This seems reasonable to me for your goals.  Feels clumsy?  Well, C++ metaprogramming is pretty clumsy.

Comment: Except that you could `template<typename T> struct highest_precision_type<std::complex<T>> { ...}` your code looks great. Well, so, you need to define how to measure "conciseness" and how to exactly reduce the "clumsiness feeling" of the code, otherwise your question is just opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::conditional<>` and @KamilCuk's comment reduces code to:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct highest_precision_type
    : std::conditional<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, long double, T>
{
};

template <typename T>
struct highest_precision_type<std::complex<T>>
{
    typedef std::complex<long double> type;
};
```

see [live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EuPqJAGYIVOss8vV).

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine but if you'd like a more compact alternative, this could be done using `std::conditional`:

```
template <typename T>
struct highest_precision_type
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>);

    using type = 
        std::conditional_t<
            std::is_unsigned_v<T>,
            std::uintmax_t,
            std::conditional_t<
                std::is_integral_v<T>,
                std::intmax_t,
                long double>
        >;
};
```

For types instantiated from templates, what Barry had in his now deleted answer looks good. This is my take on that:

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts>
struct highest_precision_type<C<Ts...>>
{
    using type = C<typename highest_precision_type<Ts>::type...>;
};

template <typename T>
using highest_precision_type_t = typename highest_precision_type<T>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/foTcPc)

Note the part in the demo that does:

```
highest_precision_type_t<std::string> s;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(s), std::basic_string<std::intmax_t>>);
```